# How to add .docx file to custom folder in outlook using addin c#

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

How to add Word Document/Excel Document file to custom folders created inside outlook using VSTO addin C#

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Object Model would not let you explicitly create a document object - you can start with adding a regular MailItem object using [MAPIFolder.Items.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861028.aspx), add the attachment, then set the `MessageClass` properly appropriately (look at an existing document item with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) - click Item or IMessage button), and save the message.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, you can use its [RDODocumentItem](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdodocumentitem.htm) object - you can either call `RDODocumentItem.SetDocument` method or call `RDOFolder.Items.Add` and specify the full path to an existing file - see http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdodocumentitem.htm for more details.

Comment: Can't we do it using Office Tools OR any open source library?

Comment: I just described above how you can do that using Outlook Object Model alone, it is just not very straightforward.

Comment: Thanks Buddy! I did it using MessageClass. But I am unable to add .msg file. Your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean Import an MSG file as a regular message, not a document item? I answered your question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501175/import-msg-file-to-outlook-custom-folder-using-c-sharp/40509642#40509642

Answer (score 0):

Outlook.DocumentItem objDocItem = ParentFolder.Items.Add("IPM.Document");

```
            //objDocItem = ParentFolder.Items.Add("IPM.Document");

            Outlook.Attachment objAtt = objDocItem.Attachments.Add(strFilePath);
            objDocItem.Subject = objAtt.FileName;


            string strFileType = Path.GetExtension(strFilePath);
            switch (strFileType)
            {
                case ".doc":
                case ".docx":
                    objDocItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Document.Word.Document.8"; break;
                case ".xls":
                case ".xlsx":
                    objDocItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Document.Excel.Sheet.8"; break;
                case ".pps":
                case ".ppt":
                case ".pptx":
                    objDocItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Document.PowerPoint.Show.8"; break;
            }


            objDocItem.Save();
```