# How to import local .msg file to Outlook folder using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to copy a local .msg file (like C:\temp\DUMMY.msg) to an Outlook folder (like AAA).

I can get the entryID of AAA folder by using MAPI.

I found [Import .msg file to outlook custom folder using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501175/import-msg-file-to-outlook-custom-folder-using-c-sharp).

I have imported library written in below.

- Visual Basic For Applications
- Microsoft Excel 15.0 object library
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft Office 15.0 object library
- Microsoft VBScript regulaer Explessions 5.5
- Microsoft Scripting Runtime
- Microsoft Forms 2.0 object library

I assigned destination Outlook folder obj to MyFolder.

```vb
If argStrEntryID = "" Then
    Set MyFolder = oApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Else
    Set MyFolder = oApp.Session.GetFolderFromID(argStrEntryID)
End If
```

How do I move the local .msg file to an Outlook folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Namespace.OpenSharedItem` specifying the MSG file fully qualified file name and then copy (`MailItem.Copy`) or move it (`MailItem.Move`).

Comment: thanks a lot !
using Namespace.OpensharedItem is good and I completed to move local files into outlook dir by using code I wrote below.

Answer (score 0):

as Dmitry mentioned, I used Namespace.OpensharedItem and it worked.

---

```
Dim Filename As String
Filename = "C:\temp\DUMMY.msg"

Dim DestOlDirID As String
DesOlDirID = "(entry id value)"

Dim oApp
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

'Get Namespace object
Dim oNamespace As Namespace
Set oNamespace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

'assign outlook folder by entry ID
Dim oFolder As Folder
Set oFolder = oApp.Session.GetFolderFromID(DesOlDirID)

Dim oItem As Object
Set oItem = oNamespace.OpenSharedItem(Filename)

'actually this move method did not delete original .msg local file. it works like copy.
oItem.Move oFolder

Set oItem = Nothing
Set oFolder = Nothing
Set oNamespace = Nothing
```